# How do I upload a WordPress Landing Page with FTP into an existing application?

Tags: wordpress, ftp, cpanel

I was recently contacted by a friend of a friend because he needed someone to upload a WordPress Landing Page to an existing website using FTP. I know a little about deployment in Java, C# and backend languages, but I've never worked with WordPress and I'm still confused about what to import to the website. They sent me the Landing Page file, and I'm still confused. They also signaled to me what subdomain they wanted the landing page to be. Here's the files inside the folder of the project.

[image: WordPress File].

I found a file inside the public_html file with the same name as the supposed subdomain but still no idea which files to import.

I already tried moving the entire WordPress file to public_html but nothing changed. I'm currently uploading all files to public_html, but I'm still not convinced this will work.

Comment: First, that's not a WordPress site your friend sent you.  Second, to display a WordPress landing page on a subdomain, you need to install WordPress - you need the whole site, plus the database that goes with that site, with certain database values altered so that it will run on the subdomain.  So it needs to be running on a platform that supports WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress creates all pages **dynamically**, i.e. especially the main parts ands contents of the page are fetched from database entries, plus there is a lot of PHP, jQuery or other scripts involved when putting the page together.

So **there no *one* HTML file that you could upload somewhere**. The page is put together "on the run" when calling it, and you won't be able to save all its components (complete HTML, CSS, assets etc.) in one file, not even in one folder...

**Edit/addition**:

Depending on the complexity of that page, you might want to try to load that page in a browser and then save it within the browser, including all dependent files (there usually are options for this when saving a page in a browser). This would create a folder with some files (HTML, images etc.), that you could upload, but that would probably *not*  be responsive, the links on the page would have to be edited, if there are forms on the page, they might miss other files to process them and so on. But if it's a simple page, it might be worth trying.